# Как в laravel обновить связанную таблицу one-to-one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Есть две таблицы posts, и posts_description. Каким образом я могу обновить обе таблицы? Получается обновить только первую. Либо удалить запись и второй таблицы, и добавить новую связанную по id строку, но, вероятно, это не правильно, т.к. будет новый id строки после каждого такого. обновления

```
 public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post->type = $request->type;
        $post->image = !empty($request->image) ? $request->image : '';
        $post->sort = !empty($request->sort) ? $request->sort : 0;
$post->postdescription->title = $request->title; // Естественно, не работает
        $post->save();
/** Здесь нужно как-то обновить значения title и дескрипшн в таблице posts_description **/

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Статья была успешно обновлена');
    }
```

Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас в модели `Post` существует отноешение `postdescription`. Тогда можете обновлять так:

```
$post->postdescription->update($request->only('title', 'description'));
```

Не забудьте добавить в модель `PostDescription` `protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];`